# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3

Tags: android, build, android-appcompat

This is an eclipse project that I migrated to android studio, it was working just fine till I upgraded android studio to the latest version today and I have this problem for hours now, can you please help me?

This is my build.gradle (module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
   compileSdkVersion 27
   buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.com"
      minSdkVersion 14
      targetSdkVersion 27
   }

   buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
         'proguard-rules.txt'
     }
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

}
```

This is my build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
   repositories {

      google()
      jcenter()


   }
  dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

  }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
      google()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because there is no version 27.0.3 of `appcompat-v7`. Check [this page](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html) to see published versions (expand the `com.android.support` -> `appcompat-v7` sections). As of right now, these 27.X versions exist:

- 27.0.0
- 27.0.1
- 27.0.2
- 27.1.0
- 27.1.1

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.3'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

Perhaps you pasted `buildToolVersion` in this.